# Align rectangles with height below each other

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to place the four rectangles below each other without any space. The code blow does this, but there is always some space between the rectangles.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (dynamicdata) at (3,2) [draw, thick, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm] {dynamic data};       
\node (staticdata)  [draw, thick, below=of dynamicdata.south, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm] {static data};
\node (text)  [draw, thick, below=of staticdata.south, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm] {text};
\node (reserved)  [draw, thick, below=of text.south, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm] {reserved}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about `below=0cm of ...` or `\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0cm]`?

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,nodes={outer sep=0pt}]`?

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,nodes={outer sep=0pt,minimum width=3cm,draw,thick, minimum height=1cm}]
\node (dynamicdata) at (3,2) [minimum height=2cm] {dynamic data};       
\node (staticdata)  [below=of dynamicdata.south] {static data};
\node (text)  [below=of staticdata.south] {text};
\node (reserved)  [below=of text.south] {reserved}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very hard to tell you where your gaps come from since you do not show us a complete code. So you could have anything in your preamble. I am assuming that you have somewhere a `\tikzset{node distance=0pt}`. In any case, apart from this, which was mentioned by leandriis in the comments, you may see the effects of `outer sep`. And then, if you have a picture in which all nodes share `thick,draw,minimum width=3cm`, you could just add to the options `nodes={outer sep=0pt,minimum width=3cm,draw,thick}` such that you do not have to type that much and can adjust things once instead of several times, if needed.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,nodes={outer sep=0pt,minimum width=3cm,draw,thick, minimum height=1cm}]
\node (dynamicdata) at (3,2) [minimum height=2cm] {dynamic data};       
\node (staticdata)  [below=of dynamicdata.south] {static data};
\node (text)  [below=of staticdata.south] {text};
\node (reserved)  [below=of text.south] {reserved}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I am pretty new to tikz and I did not know 'node distance=0pt'. Thanks.